# How to get version from sbt-dynver on command line?

Tags: bash, sbt

In order to generate dynamically the version in my sbt project I am using the [sbt-dynver](https://github.com/dwijnand/sbt-dynver) plugin. But in order to integrate the build system, I would like to obtain the version string from a bash script, something like:

```
DYNVER=`sbt dynver`
```

But the previous command does not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get what I wanted by adding the 'show' command to sbt and parsing the output value, as follows:

```
VERSION=`sbt "show dynver" | grep -oE "\w{7}-\w{8}-\w{4}"`
echo $VERSION
4bbbb2a-20171022-1508
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to ignore other SBT output by taking last line.
Also it's better to print out `version` instead of `dynver` as it affects overrides from your `version.sbt` file.

```
VERSION=$(sbt 'print version' | tail -n 1)
echo $VERSION
0.1.7-2-6853afe4
```